# Jest/Enzyme Image onload callback not being ran

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I have a `ImageLoader` class component that I am trying to test if the `onload` function on a `HTMLImageElement` is being called. It is important to note that `ImageLoader` works as intended, I just can't get the tests to run. Here is the example of my class component:

```
export default class ImageLoader extends React.Component {
  // Omitted for brevity

  setSrc = () => {
    const { src } = this.props;

    if (src) {
      this.tmpImg = new Image();

      // this.tmpImg.onload is never called
      this.tmpImg.onload = () => console.log('???');

      this.tmpImg.src = src;
    }
  }

  // Omitted for brevity
}
```

For my test I have left out what I am actually testing because I never actually get to the `onload` event (it doesn't `console.log` when the tests are running unless I manually call `this.tmpImg.onload()`).

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import ImageLoader from '../ImageLoader';

describe('ImageLoader', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ImageLoader src="A_URL_STRING" />,
    );

    // Omitted for brevity
  });
});
```

Now according to [this](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816) is issue `jsdom` has got rid of support for that, however towards the end a [comment](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-355188615) was left saying you can do it with the proper Jest setup.

I have added that to my setup but still can not get the `onload` event to fire.

Here is that setup:

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "resources": "usable"
    }
  },
```

Also in the `jsdom` repository it talks about loading subresources [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#loading-subresources).

**Update**

What drives me even more mad is I can create the tests in Code Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo6jxmmxo4) and it passes all tests.

If I download it and run it locally I get a `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

One thing to note is I moved creating the image into a promise and then resolving that promise when `onload` has been called.

Comment: 1. Are you also installed [`canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) or [`canvas-prebuilt`](https://npmjs.org/package/canvas-prebuilt) package?
 2. Also, why not to fire `load` event manually via `enzyme`s [`simulate`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html)?

Comment: You were right @AndrewMiroshnichenko, I needed to add the canvas package as a dev dependency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I figured it all out thanks to Andrew's comment above.

To make this work locally you have to have the [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) package installed with `"testEnvironmentOptions": { "resources": "usable" },` setup in the Jest section of the `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you can't use the above package, you can just overwrite `window.Image()`. Change the code to use the `window.Image()` constructor, then the following will work:

ImageLoader:

```
export default class ImageLoader extends React.Component {

  setSrc = () => {
    const { src } = this.props;

    if (src) {
      this.tmpImg = new window.Image();

      this.tmpImg.onload = () => console.log('bimpson');

      this.tmpImg.src = src;
    }
  }

}
```

Test:

```
describe('ImageLoader', () => {
    const mockImage = {
        src: null,
        onload: () => {},
        onerror: () => {}
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        window.Image = function() { return mockImage }
    });

    it("Loads a data url into an image element", (done) => {
        const wrapper = mount(
          <ImageLoader src="A_URL_STRING" />,
        );

        // Call onload or onerror to trigger the desired behaviour
        mockImage.onload();

        // Test for your expected behaviour after onload is called here
    });
});
```

Obviously it's not perfect (it'll always load every time), but if you just want to test that you're correctly setting the callbacks then it works fine.

Comment: You may also need to wrap the `mockImage.onload()` in `act`