# Image onLoad handler never called in Jest

Tags: javascript, image, jestjs, onload, jsdom

I'm trying to test loading a dataUrl into an image using Jest. I'm using JSDOM and followed the instruction to add `resources: "usable"` as an option.

The code works if I run it directly from Node, but when I try to run it within Jest, the image onLoad handler is never called, and so the test never completes.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`, {
    resources: "usable",
});

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.navigator = global.window.navigator;

const dataUrlToImage = async (dataUrl) => {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

        img.onload = function() { // Never called
            console.info('On load called'); 
            resolve(img);
        };

        img.src = dataUrl;
    }));
}

it('tests image loading', async () => {
    const r = await dataUrlToImage('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    expect(!!r).toBe(true); // This is never called
});
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you see this issue? https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816

Comment: Yes I did, and done what they mention (using `resources: "usable"` option)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest/Enzyme Image onload callback not being ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468588/jest-enzyme-image-onload-callback-not-being-ran)

Answer (score 4):

Jest relies on an old version of jsdom which only works with canvas@1. The version of jsdom you get now from npm only works with canvas@2.

So I assume you're missing either `npm install canvas@1` or `npm install canvas-prebuilt@1`.

As a side note: jest comes with jsdom built in, instead of requiring your own version, you should instead add `testEnvironmentOptions: { resources: "usable" }` to your `jest.config.js`, then you can remove all the jsdom boilerplate.